# How to update data in the datagridview during run time in VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am designing a windows form in vb.net 2010. It's a simple one with two controls. One is datagridview to display data in tabular form and another is a chart control which fetches data from the gridview to draw charts. I also have a combobox which helps to select the variable for which I would like to have the table or charts. In addition, there are two buttons, one labeled 'table' clicking on which populates the gridview with data from an external excel file. Another button labeled 'plot' plots the data that was imported into gridview.

Suppose I have three variables in the comboBox, 'Real GDP', consumption, investment. During the run-time, the first time I select any variable, it works fine.But during the same run, if I select another variable, then gridview can import the variable but plot fails to draw the chart.  **Plot can not find the variable because it is still looking for the first variable while in gridview I have the table for the second variable. It seems there is a disconnect between the gridview and plot if we select another variable after the first one is displayed.**

If I close the run and rebuild and select another variable it works fine. But again during that run if I select another variable, it fails. Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

Dim myStr1, myStr2, myStr3 As String
Dim msgStr, msgEnd, defValStr, defValEnd, _
   title, myValStr, myValEnd As String

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myStr1 = selectVariable.SelectedItem
    MsgBox("You have chosen " & myStr1)
    ' Defining a InputBox to enter Sample Period
    ' Start Period
    msgStr = "Enter your Starting time period: Between 1980 and 2012"
    defValStr = "1982"
    title = "Define Sample Time Period"
    myValStr = InputBox(msgStr, title, defValStr)
    ' End Period
    msgEnd = "Enter your Ending time period: Between 1980 and 2012"
    defValEnd = "2012"
    title = "Define Sample Time Period"
    myValEnd = InputBox(msgEnd, title, defValEnd)
    Select Case myStr1
        Case "Real GDP"
            myStr2 = "xgdp"
        Case "Consumption"
            myStr2 = "CP"
        Case "Investment"
            myStr2 = "IP"
    End Select

    myStr3 = String.Concat("select", " ", "FY", ",", myStr2, " ", "from", " ", "[Dataset$]", " ", "where", " ", "FY>=", myValStr, " ", "and", " ", "FY<=", myValEnd)
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='J:\Rushad\MOF\EViews Stuff\Data_Macro_Model.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(myStr3, MyConnection)
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
    MyConnection.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Chart1.DataSource = DtSet
    Chart1.Series.Add(myStr2)
    Chart1.Series(myStr2).XValueMember = "FY"
    Chart1.Series(myStr2).YValueMembers = myStr2
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It seems if I change the Button2 Sub from private to public, it works just fine!

Comment: In your Button2_Click, reset your chart by doing things like this: If Chart1.Series.Count > 0 then Chart1.Series.Clear

Answer (score 0):

You should try binding your data source to a BindingSource and binding the Binding source to your datagrid

```
BindingSourceExample.DataSource = DataToBind
DataGridView.DataSource = BindingSourceExample
```

at least this is how I would do it !